# Flutter and Dart plugins shown as not installed using flutter doctor

Tags: flutter

I am working normally with Android Studio developing Flutter projects.

But now, after executing the command `flutter doctor -v` the output is as follows:

[image]

The only issue shown is that Flutter and Dart plugins are not installed, but they are:

[image]

Is that a bug only or should I change something in Android Studio?

I am on flutter channel stable, on dev channel the issue is not shown, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the path to the [Flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) through settings. For detailed steps, you can refer the link attached.

The one that you carried out is enabling the Flutter IDE features.

> Installing the plugin will enable the Flutter Specific features in the
> Android Studio.

To make the Android studio to support Flutter development you need to set the path to the Flutter SDK in

> Settings -> "Languages and Frameworks"   -> Flutter -> "Set the path
> to Flutter SDK" -> Click Apply.

[image: Screenshot]

Restart the Android Studio to make the changes to reflect. After completing the setup, you can run the `flutter doctor` to confirm that everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you, but all is already set to use Flutter and Dart, like you say

Comment: You may need to terminate the current session and open a new session in terminal to run the flutter doctor command.

Comment: As you may see in my question , the issue only happens when using stable channel, using dev channel then flutter doctor shows all items as OK. May be it is a bug when using the stable channel only.

Comment: Yup. It happens sometimes !!